# Yii2: How to redirect on invalid routes?

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, url-routing, yii2-urlmanager

Instead of showing an error page I'd like to redirect the user to the start page in general, if the route is invalid (there is no controller/action like requested). To make it sound the redirection should only happen on 'normal' page requests. Though [AJAX calls](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$isAjax-detail) can be invalid as well, I don't want to send a redirect to the browser here.

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

You can override [ErrorAction class](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-erroraction)  and will implement necessary logic. For example:

```
class MyErrorAction extends \yii\web\ErrorAction
{

    public $redirectRoute;  

    public function run()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->getRequest()->getIsAjax()) {
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($this->redirectRoute)->send();
            return;
        }
        return parent::run();
    }
}
```

After it, you should add this action in a controller and configure it

```
class SiteController
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => MyErrorAction::class
                'redirectRoute' => 'site/my-page'
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

and configure [the route of error action](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-errorhandler#$errorAction-detail) in the error handler

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
]
```